# QtCreator android wont deploy

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am trying to run a simple app in android simulator. When I compile, I get the following:

```
/Users/derek/software/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -pipe -std=gnu++0x -O2 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-g++ -I../SSLTunnel -I../SSLTunnel/qtquick2applicationviewer -I../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include -I../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtQuick -I../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtQml -I../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtNetwork -I../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtGui -I../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtCore -I. -I../../software/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -I/Users/derek/software/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/default/armeabi-v7a/include -I../../software/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -I. -o main.o ../SSLTunnel/main.cpp
In file included from ../../software/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/algorithm:60:0,
                 from ../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:82,
                 from ../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:45,
                 from ../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtGui/qguiapplication.h:45,
                 from ../../Qt/5.2.1/android_armv7/include/QtGui/QGuiApplication:1,
                 from ../SSLTunnel/main.cpp:1:
../../software/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/utility:68:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/c++config.h>
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been known defects with this in the past it seems: [Issue 35616](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35616)

There was a comment in another post that says it will work if you are running gcc version 4.4:
[standalone toolchain does not find c++ includes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/KBZbYmjC62E)

Comment: I think I have found at least part of the problem. With the new SDK manager for android, I had to change ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH to default/<whatever> because it puts that default tag on there. This makes the include path have a "default" in it, which does not exist on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before.And now I have solve it.
Add these system variables to you system envirenment:
ANDROID_HOME:D:/android_sdk/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321/sdk(your android sdk)

ANDROID_NDK_HOST:windows

ANDROID_NDK_PLATFORM:android-19

ANDROID_NDK_ROOT:D:\android_ndk\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9d(your android ndk)

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:D:/android_sdk/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321/sdk(your android sdk)

and then reset qt-creator,rebuild your program .